# How to get vector of index of list in R

Tags: r, for-loop, apply

I try to get index of list, for example `set_of_paragraphs("Two sample t-test",list_new2[[1]], list_new2[[2]],list_new2[[3]],list_new2[[4]])`...and so on.

```
library(ReporteRs)
list_new <- c("Text1","Text2","String","Another Text")
my_text <- letters[1:length(list_new)]
list_new1 <- paste0(my_text, list_new,sep="")
list_new2 <- lapply(list_new1, function(i) pot(substr(i,1,1),textProperties(color="blue",vertical.align="superscript"))+substring(i,2))
```

Function `set_of_paragraphs` works only when I list all of index in a list

```
set_of_paragraphs("Two sample t-test",list_new2[[1]], list_new2[[2]],list_new2[[3]],list_new2[[4]])
```

I try to do this way, `set_of_paragraphs` gives me error

`Error in set_of_paragraphs(l, list_new2) : 
set_of_paragraphs can only contains pot objects.`

```
l <- list("Two sample t-test")
set_of_paragraphs(l,list_new2)
```

So the best way for me to do list them all like this code `set_of_paragraphs("Two sample t-test",list_new2[[1]], list_new2[[2]],list_new2[[3]],list_new2[[4]])`, but the problem, I have so many, there is any way to write loop or apply to access index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to call a function with a list of parameters you can use `do.call`. Try

```
l <- list("Two sample t-test")
do.call("set_of_paragraphs" c(l, list_new2))
```

This is the equivalent of

```
set_of_paragraphs(l[[1], list_new2[[1]], list_new2[[2]], list_new2[[3]], ...)
```

(I can not test because that package seems to require Java which I do not have installed.) Basically you put all the parameters into one big list (here I use `c()` to join two lists).